# Way to substring a string after a specified character in a string

Tags: python

Is there a way to substring what remains of a string after a particular character is encountered? I would like to use the '=' sign for this if possible. If there was a way to define logic along the lines of sub string after the second '=' sign encountered, that would be ideal. I've tried some of the other sub string solutions I have found on the internet but they haven't done what I wanted.

Thanks

Comment: Huh?  You mean like `mystring.split('=')`?  Can you give us a couple sample input strings and what you want to get out of them?

Comment: http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=n

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many different ways, one:

```
str[str.index('=')+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `str.split` here:

```
>>> s = "foo = bar"
>>> s.split('=')           # split on all occurrences of =.
['foo ', ' bar']
>>> s.split('=')[1]
' bar'
>>> ss = 'foo = bar = baz'
>>> ss.split('=')
['foo ', ' bar ', ' baz']
>>> ss.split('=', 1)       # Only split on first occurrence of =
['foo ', ' bar = baz']
>>> ss.split('=', 1)[1]
' bar = baz'
```

In both of these cases, where I use `[1]` to subscript the string, it's up to you to make sure that there is at least 2 elements in the list :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function. For example, this will give you the sub-string after the second equals:

```
your_string = "foo=bar=spam=eggs"
delimiter = '='     
delimiter.join(your_string.split(delimiter)[2:]) 
#prints "spam=eggs"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> regex = re.compile('[^=]+')    
>>> regex.findall('foo=bar=baz')
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```